# How does get manipulated a Singleton?

Tags: python, python-3.x, types, python-3.6, python-3.7

For defining a Singleton in Python (for example), we can define it as

```py
class Singleton(type):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.__instance = None
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.__instance is None:
            self.__instance = super().__call__(*args, **kwargs)
            return self.__instance
        else:
            return self.__instance

class A(object, metaclass=Singleton):
    //code
```

My question is, if we create two instances of class A, doesn't Singleton's `__init__` method get called twice? How does it manage to call the `__call__` method instead of `__init__`?

Comment: @chepner crap, missed the inheritance from `type`. I still maintain that the singleton pattern is not really necessary :)

Comment: The `else:` is your code is a syntax error.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I agree with that :) Use a module instead :)

Answer (score 1):

You overrode `__call__`, so `A.__new__` isn't called if `self.__instance` is not `None`. No call to `A.__new__`, no implicit call to `A.__init__`.

The metaclass `__init__` method does *not* become the `__init__` method of `A`; it gets called when the *`class`* statement is executed. So in this case, after

```
class A(metaclass=Singleton):
    pass
```

`A.__instance` would exist, initialized to `None` by `Singleton.__init__`.

Given your definition of `A`, `A()` evaluates as `Singleton.__call__(A)`, with `A` being bound to `self`. If `A.__instance` is still `None`,
then `type.__call__(A)` is called, which invokes `A.__new__`, creating a new instance.

---

The use of a module that juanpa.arrivillaga and I allude to replaces a class like

```
class A(metaclass=Singleton):
    x = 3
    def __init__(self, y):
        self.y = 9

    def combine(self):
        return self.x + self.y
```

with a module `A.py` that looks like

```
x = 3

def init(val):
    global y
    y = val

def combine():
    return x + y
```

Instance variables and methods become top-level functions and module globals. There's no real difference between a class attribute and an instance attribute if there is only one instance. `A.init` has to be called directly. If it doesn't take any arguments, you can omit it and put the code at the top level where it gets called upon import. (There is no parameterized form of import where `import A(3)` would import `A.py` and pass 3 as an argument to the top-level code.)

Comment: So when i create a new instance of the A object, isn't `__init__` the first method to be called? Is it `__call__`?

Comment: No; I was clarifying that as you commented. As a rule, instance methods of a metaclass become the *class* methods of its instances. `A()` becomes `Singeton.__call__(A)`, but `Singeton.__init__` is only called when the class is first defined.

Comment: So the `super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)` actually creates the A object, right? And it is necessary only for the first instance of the A class.

Comment: No, that call only initializes the class attribute `A.__instance` to `None`. It's the call to `super().__call__` that creates an instance of `A` to assign to the class attribute when necessary.